# Upside-down question mark

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04[1] with a Dvorak keyboard layout. I need to write a bunch of emails in Spanish on a daily basis and I really really need a keyboard shortcut to the inverted question mark glyph (¿), but I just can't find any. So far I've been either copying and pasting it from the character map (which is, seriously, a pain in the ass) or just not bothering with it (which I tend to avoid because it makes me look sloppy). Is there a way of defining a key combination (e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + `?`) that inputs this character?

[1] Yes, yes, I know it's 2014 and all that. I'm happy with 12.04 and I don't see the need to upgrade just because, so please don't tell me to.

Answer (score 10):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while keeping them pressed, press and release <kbd>U</kbd> then type in <kbd>00BF</kbd>, release <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, then you will have your ¿.

<sup>Source:[W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/entities.html)</sup>

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this using the compose key, in a simpler way than typing all of those characters?

Comment: Compose + e + =

Answer (score 1):

set your keyboard layout to ES

```
setxkbmap es
```

to see places of characters on keyboard, run onboard

```
onboard
```

I hope it helps you.

to revert your keyboard layout run

```
setxkbmap us
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to customise your keyboard layout to your needs.

The standard keyboard layout files are found in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`.

## Step-by-step procedure

1. Identify the keyboard layout you are using. Make a backup of it: `sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/?? ??.bak`. Change the ?? to the file you're using.
2. Make a copy of the file in your home folder.
3. Open it with Gedit or any text editor you wish.
4. Modify it by adding the necessary character in a key of your choice and save it. Each key definition will have four values (normal press, with shift, with AltGr, with AltGr + Shift).
5. Now copy the file to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` overwriting the original. Open a terminal and type `sudo cp ?? /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`.
6. Set permissions of the file to match the original: `sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/??`
7. This step might be necessary: `sudo rm /var/lib/xkb/*.xkm`.
8. Logout and login again.

Answer (score -2):

Press hold Alt + numpad 168. Press hold Alt + numpad 168.

Comment: That did not work for me.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. But I think there is something else for Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I tried in writer, and gedit under 12.04, and it didn't work.

Comment: Yours also not working.

Comment: look at the addition in my answer.

Comment: I try it myself, it just does nothing. No offence!